# Segmentation fault checking strcmp

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, strcmp, dirent.h

I am writing a function `next_node` that finds next file in the directory. node takes a directory and a filename as input.

I want it to return `NULL` if there is no other file after `bname` or if it is `"."` or `".."`. It is giving me `segmentation fault (core dumped)` ONLY when it runs inside the `if` statement of `strcmp`.

Can you explain the problem or give a solution please?

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dirent.h> // DIR opendir() closedir() struct dirent readdir()
#include <string.h> // strcmp()

char *next_node(char *dname, char *bname) {
    if (!strcmp(dname, bname)) {
        // dname same as bname
        return NULL;
    }
    DIR *dirp = opendir(dname);
    struct dirent *direntp;
    while (((direntp = readdir(dirp)) != NULL) && (strcmp(direntp->d_name, bname))) {
    }
    if ((direntp = readdir(dirp)) != NULL) {
        // if d_name is "." or ".." return NULL
        if ((strcmp(direntp->d_name, ".")) || (strcmp(direntp->d_name, ".."))) {
            return NULL;
        }
        // it can reach here with no problem
        closedir(dirp);
        return direntp->d_name;
    } else {
        closedir(dirp);
        return NULL;
    }
}

int main() {
    char *dname = ".";
    char *bname = "test.c";
    char *result = next_node(dname, bname);
    printf("%s\n", result);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Start by adding some error checking...specifically on `opendir`

Comment: This code makes no sense. Your loop body is empty.

Comment: The while loop does work given that the `bname` and `dname` exist.  I have `bname` and `dname` checked before using the function in other part of my program.

Comment: That isn't how you properly use `opendir` + `readdir`. And there are multiple code paths that orphan the opened `DIR*` regardless, all of which are flat-out bugs.

Comment: Show your code for `readdir`.

Comment: @VHS [It's a POSIX system call: `readdir`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/readdir.html).

Comment: At `if (!strcmp(direntp->d_name, ".") || (!strcmp(direntp->d_name, ".."))){
            return NULL;
        }` you leak a directory descriptor.  At `closedir(dirp);
        return direntp->d_name;` the `closedir` has invalidated `dirp` and `direntp`, so you're no longer pointing to valid memory.  You should probably use `strdup()` before calling `closedir()` to copy the name — don't forget to release it.  Your `.` and `..` test is further puzzling: you return when they're read, which means you abandon ship before reading any names because `.` and `..` are normally the first names returned.

Comment: I have the same problem, your question helped me in finding a solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have five mistakes.

1:

```
DIR *dirp = opendir(dname);
```

You don't check if this `opendir` succeeds.

2:

```
struct dirent *direntp;
while (((direntp = readdir(dirp)) != NULL) && (strcmp(direntp->d_name, bname))) {
}
if ((direntp = readdir(dirp)) != NULL) {
```

Here, you call `readdir` even if the previous loop terminated because `readdir` returned `NULL`. You want:

```
if ((direntp != NULL) && ((direntp = readdir(dirp)) != NULL)) {
```

3:

```
    if ((strcmp(direntp->d_name, ".")) || (strcmp(direntp->d_name, ".."))){
```

Converting an integer to a boolean is equivalent to asking if it's not zero. The `strcmp` function returns zero on a match. So asking if it's not zero is asking if it's *not*  match. But everything is either not a match for "." or not a match for ".."! You want:

```
    if ((!strcmp(direntp->d_name, ".")) || (!strcmp(direntp->d_name, ".."))){
```

4:

```
    // it can reach here with no problem
    closedir(dirp);
    return direntp->d_name;
```

You just returned a pointer into a directory that you closed, rendering the pointer invalid. You need to decide what the lifespan of the returned pointer is supposed to be and perhaps allocate some memory to return.

Maybe:

```
    char *ret = strdup (dirent->d_name);
    closedir(dirp);
    return ret;
```

Note that the caller needs to `free` the returned string when it's done with it.

5:

```
char *result = next_node(dname, bname);
printf("%s\n", result);
```

This will fail if the `result` is `NULL`. Try:

```
char *result = next_node(dname, bname);
printf("%s\n", (result == NULL) ? "NULL" : result);
```

Comment: Do I lost the chance to free `ret` if function return `NULL`?

Comment: @katharineKim With my suggested change, `strdup` is only called if we're going to return something other than `NULL`.

Comment: Thanks for explaining my mistakes. I have took your approach but it stills give me segment-fault when it runs inside `if (strcmp) {}`.

Comment: Thanks for helping this far. I finally found the problem, it was silly.  The problem was caused by printing `NULL` in `Main`

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*.

Update: The problem was printing NULL in main. Printing NULL only gives segfault in Linux but not Windows.

Answer (score -1):

strcmp returns 0 If there is no difference between them try the following instead

```
if (strcmp(dname, bname)) {
    return NULL;
}
```

edit: also I'm not sure what you're issue is I'm compiling this using gcc on windows and i'm not having any issues with it.

Comment: It wouldn't be any issue on windows because `readdir` has different order to linux.  In the case of windows, the code will never reach a case that `direntp->d_name` is `"."` or `".."`

Comment: @katharineKim good point, also a TIL. compiled it on linux and got the segmentation fault. Anyway, I believe your issue isn't the if statement but the `return NULL;` part. You need to return a `char*`. I tried to do `return "\0";` and it worked on the linux machine so maybe try that? You still get a segmentation fault with the rest of the code that way but David seems to have answered that for you

Comment: Interesting found @zee.  Since `char*` is a pointer and `NULL` is also a pointer, I think it should be fine returning `NULL`.  I wonder why it worked returning NULL anywhere else in the code but not in the if that i used `strcmp`.